# How can I remove the restrictions of having Surname and Email as a required field?

Tags: profile, edit

I keep getting this error "First Name and Last Name OR an email OR an OpenID in the Primary Location should be set."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try these? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16814/bogus-error-mandatory-fields-first-name-and-last-name-or-email-address-missing-f